# Collect Geometry is not working properly when combining list of geometries with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, geometry, qgsrubberband

I am developing a Plugin which requires to combine list of geometries. I am using `QgsGeometry.collectGeometry` utility of PyQGIS for this. Code is attached below.

```py
def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event): 
    self.layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
   
        if self.GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) == 1: 
            if not self.capturing:
                self.startCapturing()
            self.capturedPoints = []
            self.addVertex1(event.pos())
            self.click += 1        # increment the click counter
            if self.click == 3:   
                self.capturing = False 
                circularRing = QgsCircularString()
                circularRing.setPoints([
                self.curvedPoints[0],
                self.curvedPoints[1],
                self.curvedPoints[2]])
                geom_from_curve = QgsGeometry(circularRing)
                self.geoms.append(geom_from_curve)
                self.rubberBand.addGeometry(geom_from_curve)
                self.rubberBand.show()
                self.rbs.append(self.rubberBand) 
                self.click=0
                self.curvedPoints=[]
        if self.GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) == 0:
            if not self.capturing:
                self.startCapturing()
            self.addVertex(event.pos())
            polyline = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(self.capturedPoints)
            self.geoms.append(polyline)
            self.rubberBand.addGeometry(polyline)
            self.rubberBand.show()
            self.rbs.append(self.rubberBand)  
    if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:   
        self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(str(self.geoms))
        g = QgsGeometry.collectGeometry(self.geoms)
        f = QgsFeature()
        f.setGeometry(g)
        fet = self.layer.getFeature(0)
        prov1 = self.layer.dataProvider()
        self.layer.startEditing()
        prov1.addFeatures([f])
        f.setAttributes(fet.attributes())
        self.layer.commitChanges()
        self.layer.updateExtents()
        iface.mapCanvas().refresh()              
        self.stopCapturing() 
        for item in self.rbs:
            self.canvas.scene().removeItem(item)
        self.geoms = []
```

`'geoms = []'` is defined as global variable within the class.It looks like:

```
[<QgsGeometry: LineString (-12687.15850588028843049 -3710.08813120553531917, -6887.5051258964886074 -4528.86272602677854593)>, <QgsGeometry: CircularString (-6614.58026095607783645 -4528.86272602677854593, -5113.49350378380040638 -3232.46961755981101305, -5181.72472001890128013 -503.22096815567056183)>]
```

The code is giving correct result in case of 1)start drawing with CircularString and then drawing LineString. But it doesn't convert CircularString geometries in feature in 2) reverse case. Geometries are appended correctly in `'Geoms'` for both the cases hence it looks like `g = QgsGeometry.collectGeometry(self.geoms)` is skipping CircularString in case of generating LineString at first. Eventually all the geometries are lineString only. What can be the issue here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QgsGeometry.collectGeometry`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a42cbc7025e8c13e697b4fd3ad365ea2f) creates a new multipart geometry from a list of given geometry objects. The first object in the list infers the type of the resulting geometry in this operation.

Your first case works, because by providing the `CircularString` geometry first, the output type of `collectGeometry` will be a `MultiCurve` and adding a `LineString` geometry as part of a  `MultiCurve` is perfectly valid.

However, when providing the `LineString` first, output type will be `MultiLineString`. And your second geometry, the `CircularString` which is a curved geometry, can not be added as part of a straight geometry such as `MultiLineString`. Therefore you observed that the second geometry was skipped.

A solution would be to capture the 'straight' segment as curved geometry right from the beginning. I guess you would need replace `QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(self.capturedPoints)` with something like `QgsGeometry(QgsCircularString(self.capturedPoints))` (Note that I didn't test this.)

Or you could convert all straight geometries with [`QgsGeometry.convertToCurves`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#aa6ce5dc3a40f1a85def41a4f78f6fcdf) to curved types before passing them to `collectGeometry`, which I put together in the example below:

```py
wkt_line = 'LineString (-12687.15850588028843049 -3710.08813120553531917, -6887.5051258964886074 -4528.86272602677854593)'
wkt_circular = 'CircularString (-6614.58026095607783645 -4528.86272602677854593, -5113.49350378380040638 -3232.46961755981101305, -5181.72472001890128013 -503.22096815567056183)'

geom_line = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt_line)
geom_circular = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt_circular)

# your first case 
geom_collected1 = QgsGeometry.collectGeometry([geom_circular, geom_line])
print(geom_collected1) # <QgsGeometry: MultiCurve ...

# your second case, not returning what you expect
geom_collected2 = QgsGeometry.collectGeometry([geom_line, geom_circular])
print(geom_collected2) # <QgsGeometry: MultiLineString ...

# your second case modified, now returning the same as first case
geom_collected3 = QgsGeometry.collectGeometry([geom_line.convertToCurves(), geom_circular])
print(geom_collected3) # <QgsGeometry: MultiCurve ...
```